# Very less particles are spawning in fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I was following default cube's honey tutorial https://youtu.be/viiOpt0JhfU?t=154 and ran into some problems.

The number of particles that are spawning are very less than they should be.

**MY RESULT:**
[image]

**DEFAULT CUBE'S RESULT:**
[image]

BLEND FILE(WITH CACHE): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D0acGD0vPbkLnJ7hS5N2ZytsLoCiEbJQ/view?usp=sharing

When I increased the resolution, I got this weird effect:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing resolution or scale of your domain?

Comment: can you please use https://blend-exchange.com/ to provide your blend file. I even couldn't download your blend file from google...don't know why, but blend-exchange just works.

Comment: I did but it didn't help much(See the edit)

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/3c6d7596ee6d4dad80a8ab23d149c444                Here it is

Comment: You will have to rebake the cache